# jekyll & isotope - post images getting cutoff

Tags: css, jquery-isotope

i've been using Jekyll for my personal site for a while now, and i love it, but recently i've decided to change up the look a bit. i'm using Jekyll/liquid functions to display preview images associated with each project/post on the homepage, which then link to their respective full post. i'd like to use Isotope to fit together all those preview images nicely on the page.

following the Isotope docs, i got the script running, but my images keep getting cut off. as i said, i'd like them to be all fit together, tetris style, filling up the page.

[image: isotope-cutoff]

they're just test images for now, and the borders are around them only for debugging purposes. all the code is [available on github](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/tree/the-river) to browse through.

any help is very much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: asked my roommate, we did some troubleshooting and it looks like Isotope was targeting the images before Jekyll could bring them in, thus giving them a height of 0. we added a really hacky fix, which makes Isotope wait 400ms before running - it works, but if anyone has a more elegant solution, i'm all ears.
    `<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var $container = $('.content-body');
        console.log('in isotope start');
        $container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.work-block'
        });
      }, 400);  
    });
  </script>`

Answer (score 1):

The Isotope documentation provides the answer: you need to use the `imagesLoaded` plugin. The plugin will wait to load Isotope until *after* the images have loaded (and thus the height of the container has been set).

Isotope doc page [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin).

Download and call the plugin, then change your Isotope call to something like (from the docs):

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Alternatively, if the images are all the same height, you probably could set the height of the image containers with CSS.

Comment: beautiful, thank you very much Andrew. worked like a charm. next time i need to poke around the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: It's a little hidden. I found it a few years ago through a Google search.  Good luck with the new site :)